# Modeling variance-covariance matrix calculation in or-tools

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I am tasked with automating an Excel Solver solution into our application. I came across [or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) and it appeared close to what I wanted - though I'm unsure as this is my first try at the SAT related problem space.

I have about 30 constraints and 1 objective. Luckily, I was able to model all constraints into or-tools, but adding the objective keeps returning a `Not an integer linear expression` error. The calculation I'm trying to minimize is a variance-covariance matrix one:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
weights = [0] * 14 # 14 different weights optimize on
values = [...] # Values corresponding to the weights
varcovmat = [[...],[...],[...], ...] # Square Matrix, 14x14

for i in range(0, len(weights)):
        weights[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, 'w'+str(i))

# Add some constraints
model.Add(cp_model.LinearExpr.Sum(weights) == 10000)
model.Add(cp_model.LinearExpr.ScalProd(weights, values) == 2000000)

# Add the Objective
expressions = [0]*len(cov)
for i in range(0, len(cov)):
   expressions[i] = sum([y*x for x,y in zip(weights, [int(x[i]*100) for x in cov])])

model.Minimize(sum([weights[i] * expressions[i] for i in range(0, len(cov))])) # Here is where the error is thrown
```

Running this, the following is thrown:

```
TypeError: Not an integer linear expression: (((((((((((((((100 * w0)) + (36 * w1)) + (5 * w2)) + (30 * w3)) + (-14 * w4)) + (12 * w5)) + (-8 * w6)) + (10 * w7)) + -w8) + (-15 * w9)) + (-13 * w10)) + (-13 * w11)) + (-11 * w12)) + (-6 * w13))
```

Is this a problem type I can use or-tools to solve? I know if I omit the objective, I can search for all solutions and pick the winning solution but this is a rather long/cumbersome method.

Is there a way to get this problem modeled into or-tools correctly or maybe a different feature of or-tools I should be looking at?

Any guidance/help would be much appreciated!

Other variation and error output I tried:

```py
# Add the Objective
expressions = [0]*len(cov)
for i in range(0, len(cov)):
    expressions[i] = cp_model.LinearExpr.ScalProd(weights, [int(x[i]*100) for x in cov])

model.Minimize(cp_model.LinearExpr.ScalProd(weights, expressions))
```

```
TypeError: Not an integer: 100 * w0 + 36 * w1 + 5 * w2 + 30 * w3 - 14 * w4 + 12 * w5 - 8 * w6 + 10 * w7 - w8 - 15 * w9 - 13 * w10 - 13 * w11 - 11 * w12 - 6 * w13
```

Comment: Typically Mean-Variance models are solved with Quadratic Programming (or these days Cone Programming) solvers. OR-Tools is used for different types of problems. You may want to have a look at CVXPY.

Comment: Ahhh - thank you! I stumbled across scipy and have gotten closer to my goal, trying out CXPY next!

Comment: If you create a new variable for each linearexpr, equal them, and save that in `expressions` instead, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Erwin's comments it turns out or-tools is not the right tool for the job - found success using [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Unfortunately, CVXPY did not like the inputs - guessing the values were no longer making it a convex optimization problem.

Comment: Mean-Variance problems are convex. The variance-covariance matrix should be (almost) positive-semi definite (to verify print the eigenvalues). If this is caused by small floating-point inaccuracies (and the eigenvalues are almost non-negative) we often can repair this by a perturbation of the diagonal (some solvers do this automatically). Anyway, you may want to talk to someone who knows a bit more about these types of models.